# Why an HTML element retrieved from another page with AJAX doesn't respond to scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Well, i have this problem with a larger script but I will make it simple

Let's supouse this is my script

```
$("a").click(function(){
   alert("test");
});
```

So, everytime someone click on an hyperlink, it will alert the user.

But when i retrieve an  element from another page with AJAX, the script isn't activated when someone click on it.

Does anyone knows? Thanks

Comment: You might have to add the listener again to the newly added elements.

Comment: Event delegation ~ `$(document).on('click', 'a', function() { alert('test'); })`

Comment: That worked @Phil thanks! But i have another question, why does that work and Ayush answer doesn't?

Comment: @Raba Ayush's answer was no different than what you already had